# How to Insert 0 in the Existing table

Tags: mysql

> table studentinfo:

```
TID       BADGEID     NAME        Location    Addr
122        233.01      Katy         GA         GA-54
123        234.02      tery         GA         GA-54
```

I want to insert 0 after. like below

```
  TID       BADGEID     NAME        Location    Addr
    122        233.001      Katy         GA         GA-54
    123        234.002      tery         GA         GA-54
```

I have this solution in my mind not sure it's correct. worried if it's going to mess my data:

```
update studentinfo
set BADGEID = '.###'
where location = 'GA'
```

Comment: Your current query is going to update BADGEID = '.###' for all the records with the location GA. Are you trying to insert a new row? Or update existing ones. It's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
UPDATE studentinfo
SET BadgeID = CAST(CAST(BadgeID as INT) + ABS(BadgeID-CAST(BadgeID AS INT))/10 AS 
Decimal(10,3))
WHERE location = 'GA'
```

Or;

```
UPDATE studentinfo
SET BadgeID = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
BadgeID),'.','.0'))
WHERE location = 'GA'
```